# ASP.NET MVC : make the font style bold in the list

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bold, font-style

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgmvi.png)

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I want to make the font style bold. But I guess `addList` and `insertList` don't have bold property. How can I do it ?

Comment: Could you write code to your question?

Comment: var bulletedListCertificate = document.AddList( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CertificateName) ? ToTitleCase(item.CertificateName) : "", 2, ListItemType.Bulleted);
                        document.InsertList(bulletedListCertificate, new Font("Arial"), 10);

Comment: try to replace second line to: `document.InsertList(bulletedListCertificate, new Font("Arial",12,FontStyle.Bold), 10);`